# Disable one Selection Box based on a Selection in another

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, cascadingdropdown

I have two selection boxes in the same form. I would like to have one disabled based on some of the options that can be selected in the other selection box. I'm looking for a solution in JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Do your elements have ids?  You want to bind the Change event for one and then use it to modify the disabled attribute of the other.  Markup would help, but it's certainly doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and do something like this

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    if(...) {
        $('#select2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

more info here http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

And if you dont use jquery you can do it like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="select1" onchange="disable()">

function disable() {
    if(...) {
        document.getElementById('select2').disabled='disabled';
    }
}
```